# Google App Engine (GAE) - Flexible Environment - Jetty Issue

Tags: java, maven, google-app-engine

After using `mvn appengine:deploy`, we receive a BUILD SUCCESSFUL message... but when you navigate to the URL... the following message is received:

```
Error 404 - Not Found.

No context on this server matched or handled this request.
Contexts known to this server are:
/ ---> o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@4566e5bd{/,file:///var/lib/jetty/webapps/root/,UNAVAILABLE}{/root.war} [failed]

Powered by Jetty:// 9.4.5.v20170502
```

I almost feel like the WAR is being deployed to the wrong directory on the AppEngine, causing Jetty to not be able to locate. Any ideas?

Comment: Getting the same error. with the gradle plugin

Answer (score 0):

It turns out Jetty requires two configuration files (web.xml and applicationContext.xml), web.xml defines the DispatcherServlet and it's configuration location, applicationContext.xml indicates that spring should use component-scanning and annotation-driven configuration.