# How to get started on Google App Engine for current GlassFish solution

Tags: java, google-app-engine, glassfish, google-cloud-platform

I'm currently running my Java application on a GlassFish server on AWS-EB.
Since our front-end is already running on the Google Cloud Platform, I would like to migrate my back-end to GCP as well.

I tried the Jelastic interface but I was not happy with the speed results.
Now I'm looking to deploy my application on the App Engine but when I deploy my current .war file, I get the following error:

```
Error 404 - Not Found.
No context on this server matched or handled this request.
Contexts known to this server are:

/ ---> o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@7e0b0338{/,file:///var/lib/jetty/webapps/root/,UNAVAILABLE}{/root.war} [failed]
```

I guess I'm missing something, since GCP is using Jetty as a server.
I'm a bit lost and I hope you guys can point me in the right direction to make this migration successful.

Comment: "I tried the Jelastic interface but I was not happy with the speed results" - what exactly did not work well for you? which Jelastic provider have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

It's suggested [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44551221/google-app-engine-gae-flexible-environment-jetty-issue) that Jetty requires two configuration files (**web.xml** and **applicationContext.xml**).

As well as this, the original poster in the issue above stated that they solved their issue in [**this GitHub post**](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-maven-plugin/issues/86) by rebuilding their project before deploying.